# Join 2 tables with Group By Date

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I have two queries that I’m trying to combine, but I’m having an issue and I believe it has to do with the GROUP BY Date when I do LEFT JOIN. The date formats are the same and the only column I need to include into query 1 from query 2 is Qty WHERE Date = Date.

Any Help would be appreciated!

Thanks
Angel

Query 1

```
$dbGreeterReport = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cars, Date, SUM(Families), SUM(People), Families, People, Testimony, SUM(IF(Prayer = 'Yes', 1, 0)) AS Prayer, COUNT(DISTINCT Zipcode) AS Zipcodes    
FROM Greeter_Detail
WHERE $dateRange
GROUP BY Date");
```

Query 2

```
$dbSalv = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT *, Date
FROM Salv
WHERE $dateRange
GROUP BY Date");
```

I tried Join as follows:

```
LEFT JOIN Greeter_Detail ON Greeter_Detail.DATE = Salv.Date
```

I'm looking for the results to be as follows grouped by rows by dates:

```
Date    Cars    Families    People  Prayer    Qty
01/06/2024  177 323 1,199   162  5
```

Comment: At the very least [Edit] your question to add some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: The second query has no aggregation functions. It should get an error because of that, unless you disable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.

Comment: Is `Date` a unique column in `Salv`?

Comment: Please provide sample input data and the corresponding expected results.

Comment: Yes, Date is a unique column in Salv

Comment: **egad** `select * from salv` when you only need Qty from that table. Don't do that. What happens if there are several rows in `Salv` that share the same date? Do you need to `sum(qty)`?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by  It is advised that you turn `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` **ON**

Comment: one other thing, are the columns called "Date" actually "date" or "datetime" or "timestamp" data types? Do you need to "truncate" the data to just the date using `date()` function? e.g.  `Greeter_Detail.DATE(datecolumn)` and/or `Salv.Date(datecolumn)`

Answer (score 0):

MySQL [date/time data types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) include types that can be more precise than "date" e.g. 2024-01-08 does not equal 2024-01-08 17:23:47 - but you might only see "2024-01-08" on the screen. So when attempting to join data by "date" make sure both sides on the join are only date and not more precise than that. This can be done using function `DATE(datecolumn)` or `DATE_FORMAT(datecolumn,'%y-%m-%d')`.

**GROUP BY queries in MySQL**

Another, very important, point to make about your queries is that they rely on a **very imprecise** feature of MySQL and one that you should NOT rely on.

Imagine this

```
insert into test (code1, code2, value) values
  ('a','x',100)
, ('a','y',200)
, ('a','z',300)
```

and this query:

```
select
     *
   , sum(value)
from test
group by
     code1
```

You might expect only one row as the result, such as this:

| code1 | code2 | sum(value) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | x | 600 |

**but why is code2 "x"?** After all the source row for 'x' only has a value of 100 so why has MySQL shown "x"?

Answer: Because it is arbitrary (and therefore potentially misleading!), for more see [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) and  [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/p7XKBLll)

To permanently avoid these arbitrary/misleading results requires more effort by you when forming group by queries - and to help enforce this you should set ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY ON in (all) your MySQL environment(s). [Ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)

**Suggested Queries**

Once you have ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY on, you will have to be more specific about the non-aggregating columns you include in queries, for example:

```
SELECT
      DATE(date) AS date
    , COUNT(*) AS Cars
    , SUM(Families)
    , SUM(People)
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Prayer = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Prayer
    , COUNT(DISTINCT Zipcode) AS Zipcodes
FROM Greeter_Detail
WHERE $DATERANGE
GROUP BY DATE(date)

SELECT
     DATE(date) AS date
   , SUM(Qty) AS Qty
FROM Salv
WHERE $DATERANGE
GROUP BY DATE(date)
```

Note, now there are no columns where MySQL needs to choose an arbitrary value to display (e.g. `select *` has been replaced with `SELECT DATE(date) AS date`).

Also note that now the "date" columns are more likely to find exact matches when you join the 2 results together.

Comment: I turned on ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY and the above query did not work. I thought it would. A bit more info is that the Date field is just text 01/09/2024. This is the case for both tables. Also, there is no need to SUM the Qty field as there is only one entry for that date in the database. I also tried the OP's query with the LEFT JOIN and that didn't help either and I had previously tried that as well. Any more suggestions would be appreciated. You would think this to be a simple query. But it's beyond my level of expertise.

Comment: "Did not work" is not helpful. Exactly what happened? Did you get an error message - what was it? The "date" column is "just text" - so the actual data type of that column is varchar? Please provide the **table definitions** plus **sample data** and the **expected result** you want from that sample data.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    G.Date,
    COUNT(*) AS Cars,
    SUM(G.Families) AS Families_Greeter,
    SUM(G.People) AS People_Greeter,
    G.Testimony,
    SUM(IF(G.Prayer = 'Yes', 1, 0)) AS Prayer_Greeter,
    COUNT(DISTINCT G.Zipcode) AS Zipcodes_Greeter,
    S.Qty
FROM Greeter_Detail G
LEFT JOIN Salv S ON G.Date = S.Date
WHERE $dateRange
GROUP BY G.Date;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: also please learn how to format your answer, code is indented by 4 spaces & there is a toolbar button for this `{}`

Comment: This is Resolved. The issue was that the $dateRange contained Date and had to be specified to G.Date. Thanks for all the responses.